# I think I planted seeds too deep in Jiffy7 peat pellets - How do I fix this?

Tags: seedlings, germination

I planted a 72-spot tray with a variety of things, mostly herbs, some veggies. I've had only a handful of things germinate. About 10-12 of the peat pellets have sprouted. I'm concerned that I probably planted the seeds too deeply, so I'm wondering how I can fix this? The tray has been planted for about 2 weeks, perhaps a little more.

Is it likely that the ungerminated seeds are mouldy by this point? Should I leave them undisturbed in the environment they're in and keep hope that they'll pop up?

- Environment: Basement, in my computer server room.
- Temperature: 81F (held constant by environmental control equipment)
- Relative humidity: 34% (but the plastic lid is on)
- Lighting: Four 32-watt T8 fluorescent bulbs hanging about 3" over the tops of the seed trays.

Seeds planted:

- Tomato
- Basil
- Kale
- Fennel
- Cucumber
- Artichoke
- Winter squash
- others

For comparison, here is a different seed tray with some different stuff planted, but the seeds are nowhere near as deep; they are almost sitting on the surface. This second seed tray is in the exact same environment, the only major difference is the planting depth. Both trays have a wide variety of stuff in them.

(I have a web cam taking 1 picture of my seed tray every minute, to be compiled into a time-lapse video after I'm done growing stuff)

Taken at 2015-05-01 23:00
[image: other tray #1]

Taken at 2015-05-02 11:00 (12 hours later)
[image: other tray #2]

Comment: How deep did you plant them?

Answer (score 2):

Wait, or plant new seeds higher up (leave the ones below), or toss the pellets and start new ones with seeds higher up.

FWIW, in an earlier question on sprouting basil, particularly, I found some research that indicated variable (cooler in dark period) rather than steady temperatures and 16 (13?) rather than 24 hours of light were beneficial, at least for basil. [Basil & Catnip Fail to Germinate](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16262/basil-catnip-fail-to-germinate)

Comment: I will try moving the tray to a different location. Ironically, the basil is one of the few things with 100% germination.