# Will freezing kill basil seeds?

Tags: seeds, basil

I've got some basil plants outside (Spicy Globe Bush), which have gone to seed. I'm wondering if there's any chance the seeds will survive a northern (USA) winter and germinate next year. Is there?

Comment: Isn't the risk is that they germinate and then die off with another frost?

Comment: [This question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16262/basil-catnip-fail-to-germinate) (and its associated answer) may be of interest.

Comment: FYI, I've grown it a number of times, and I don't believe it's ever re-seeded when given the opportunity. Summer savory will, though. I'm in zone 6 in a Bsk climate with hot summers.

Answer (score 2):

You should harvest the seed and keep in a cold but less freezing place (shelter, car box).

It is in any case good to change place of the basil, and it will also simplify spring work.

So I would harvest now the seeds, keep in cold, and in late winter I would pot them (e.g. in your house). Only later, I would put in full soil.  This also helps you to have earlier basil leaves. The plant in any case endure the entire season.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you the effect of certain temps on the seeds, but I do know that basil seeds need cold over the winter in order to germinate. I'd take some and follow Giacomo's advice, but I'd also shake some in a pot, on top of the soil, and put a plastic bag over the top to keep out leaves and other seeds till the spring. Then see what they do.